# Protractor does not see the element's children

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have the function

```
var goThrough = function(opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement;
    var matches = [];
    var addMatchingLeaves = function(element) {
        if (element.children) {
            if (element.children.length === 0) {
                matches.push(element);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; ++i) {
                addMatchingLeaves(element.children[i]);
            }
        }
    };
    addMatchingLeaves(using);

    return matches;
};
```

Then I call it in test as

> amountOfElements = goThrough(element(by.css('.form-group')));

The html itself is

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password"> 
</div>
```

The problem is that function does not see the children of .form-group. I've tried with other elements but result is the same, function does not go inside first "if"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element(by.css('.form-group'))` returns an [`ElementFinder`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder), not the DOM element you need to query its `children`. This works kinda slow if you have a lot of elements but does the job:

```
var getLeafs = function(node) {
    return node.all(by.css('*')).filter(function(child) {
        return child.all(by.xpath('*')).count().then(function(childrenCount) {
            return childrenCount === 0;
        });
    });
};
```

It returns the elements in the context of `node` who have no children.

Usage:

```
var leafs = getLeafs(element(by.css('.form-group')));

leafs.count().then(function(c) {
    console.log(c);
});
```

Comment: no, it does not help to go inside first if... I've put console.log there and it works only when i have "if (!element.children)"

Comment: After multiple modifications, this one should be working